# Exclude lstlistoflistings cite of bibliography sources

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, listings

I have a `\lstlistoflistings` in my document. And I am referencing some of the code. However, in the bibliography it appears to be citing them as if there was an explicit citation whereas for `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` it does not happen.

[image]

This is the table of contents.

[image: This appears in the table of figures.]

This appears in the table of figures.

[image: This appears in the table of listings too.]

This appears in the table of listings too.

[image: Picture of laptop on page 3 and its citation.]

Picture of laptop on page 3.

[image: Listing citation on page 16]

Listing citation on page 16

[image: References/Bilbiograhpy]

References/Bilbiograhpy.

Latex thinks that in the `\listoflistings` I want to cite the reference but I want to cite them later in the Appendix and not here in the table of contents region.

The thing is, is it possible to exclude the list of codes from being cited as the first one in `\printbibliography` just as the List of Figures and List of Tables. Otherwise, they appear as the first item of the Bibliography.

```
\documentclass[10pt, titlepage]{report}

%% preamble
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% To input code
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}% Listing -> Code
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Codes

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,citestyle=numeric,sorting=none,hyperref,backend=biber,backref,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
% \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{3pt}
\urlstyle{tt}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\input{title}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
% Modify Table of Contents line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.75}\normalsize
\clearpage
% \vspace{10mm} \hfill 
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
% \vspace{10mm} \hfill
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}


\clearpage
% \vspace{10mm} \hfill 
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\FloatBarrier
\clearpage
% \vspace{10mm} \hfill
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\normalsize
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Codes}

% Re normalise line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}\normalsize
% \input{sections/00_nomenclature}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/image.jpg}
    \caption{source: Unsplash \cite{california_university_specification}}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab, label={lst:JB2008_atmospheric_model_function}, caption=Jacchia-Bowman JB2008 Atmospheric Density Model. Source: Matlab and Jacchia-Bowman \cite{Bowman2008_JB2008}.]{Code/Atmospheric_model_JB2008/JB2008.m}

\clearpage \printbibliography



\end{document}
```

Here is an example in Overleaf:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbnfnbhxxzws

Comment: Let me get this right: you're using citations unsorted (in order of appearance, not sorted by name), and you want sources to appear later in the list. Do you want citations in the sections to always come in last, or is the problem that a `\lstlistoflistings` at the start of your document already cites them very early, and they should come at the point the `\section` is?

Comment: It should be possible to exclude the list of codes from citation tracking, but how that can be done strongly depends on your document class and on the package/code that generates the list of codes. Please show us a small example document that reproduces your setup and the effect you are asking about with as little code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). We won't be able to help you properly if we don't know how you generate the list of codes.

Comment: @VincentKuhlmann Exactly what you said! Your explanation is way better than mine. As you mentioned, I am using unsorted citations and I would like them to come where the section is, but they come cited early in the `\lstlistoflistings`. Do you know how to exclude them or cite them where the `\section` is?

Comment: @moewe Yes! Here I reproduce my issue:
[link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbnfnbhxxzws). It shows how the code reference which actually is on the latest page comes first in the Bibliography as it appears in the `\lstlistoflistings` page in the table of contents.

Comment: Please don't provide the MWE only as Overleaf link. Not everyone has an Overleaf account and it is no guaranteed that the project remains accessible as is in the future. (See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8402/35864) Please minimise the example further so that it can be pasted as code directly into the question.

Comment: @moewe I'll do it right now! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` needs to write some code to the files used to build up the various tables/lists of .... By default `biblatex` has code to deal with `.toc`, `.lof` and `.lot`.

The relevant code for `.lol` (`listings`' list of listings) is

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \blx@immediate@addtocontents{lol}{%
     \boolfalse{citerequest}%
     \boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \boolfalse{backtracker}\relax}}
\makeatother
```

If you get an error about `\blx@immediate@addtocontents` being undefined, use

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\blx@immediate@addtocontents[2]{%
  \blx@auxwrite\@auxout
    {\let\label\@gobble \let\index\@gobble \let\glossary\@gobble}%
    {\string\@writefile{#1}{#2}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \blx@immediate@addtocontents{lol}{%
     \boolfalse{citerequest}%
     \boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \boolfalse{backtracker}\relax}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none, backref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \blx@immediate@addtocontents{lol}{%
     \boolfalse{citerequest}%
     \boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \boolfalse{backtracker}\relax}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\cleardoublepage
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=A floating example \autocite{nussbaum}]
Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: citation in lol has number 3.]

Comment: This was it! Thanks for your help!